# Wrong measurement of DSO-5200A?

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement

I'm using a DSO-5200A from Voltcraft and noticed the voltage measurement represented incorrectly (it is doubled).
Any ideas how to reset this?

[image]

Channel 1 (green) measures a (noisy) 5V and has a Vmean measurement of 10V.
Channel 2 (yellow) measures the DSO's own calibration square wave. Frequency is measured correctly, but the mean value is again wrong.
The cursors correctly indicate a voltage difference of 2V.

Comment: I see you have both channels set to 10x; are you using 10x probes? Setting the scope to 10x while using 5x probes would cause this problem, but you don't see 5x probes very often.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 10x probes.

Comment: Does the CAL signal have a 50 ohm resistor inside? and expects an external 50 ohm termination resistor?

Comment: The DSO and probes used to give the correct measurement (for every signal, CAL included) up to 1 or 3 weeks ago. So, i think it has to be a setting somewhere in the software rather than in the hardware.   But ill check your suggestion.

Comment: Do note the signal itself is represented correctly. Its both 2V/div. The green and yellow dots/lines are correct, the yellow signal fits within 1 div and green one in 2.5 div. The **measurement** however is wrong (as is the trigger level).